# Unable to mount MatshitaDVD-RAM UJ-850 on Toshiba Satellite A205-S5843. Suddenly quit working about a year ago under 12.04LTS

Tags: mount, dvd

Unable to mount the DVD under disk management in Application it is showing me :
MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ-850S (1.40)

---

---

Serial number is being displayed

Answer (score 0):

Here is some info I was able to find, although I'm not sure that a resolution has been found for your problem. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=771313

It seems that you aren't the only person having this problem, so maybe there is a fix out there.